Where do I find the fingerprints gpg keys used to sign Linux Mint software?
Where do I find the fingerprints of the gpg keys used to sign

the ISO images of the Linux Mint?
Linux Mint packages?

I would like to find a place where I can download them using a secured method (https).

You can retrieve the Linux Mint signing key over a TLS-secured connection by running
gpg --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key "27DE B156 44C6 B3CF 3BD7  D291 300F 846B A25B AE09"

If you have a Linux Mint setup, the key is in the linuxmint-keyring package.

You expressively say it is a TLS-secured connection and there is hkps:// in the command. I searched Wikipedia for it but I found no article on it. is hkps:// a TLS-secured version of hkp:// like https:// is a secured version of http://?

Yes; it isn’t mentioned much, but see for example the description of the --hkp-cacert option.

Stephen, 27DE B156 44C6 B3CF 3BD7  D291 300F 846B A25B AE09 is the Linux Mint ISO Signing Key. It looks like gpg --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key "A6616109451BBBF2" is the right command for the Linux Mint Repository Signing Key. A6616109451BBBF2 was mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386738/how-to-install-chromium-from-the-linux-mint-repositories-in-ubuntu. Is there one site where Linux Mint publishes the Key IDs for all those keys?
